# Strophe + Openfire connection disconnected repeatedly

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am using **Openfire 3.9.3** and had created web chat application with `strope.js`. When the less number of user on **openfire** were there the connection was stable. but there are lots of users registered on that app.
   Users are not online still my connection disconnected repeatedly I again connect `on_disconnected()`. The connection is made but again it get disconnected with

```
NetworkError: 404 Invalid SID. - http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/
```

is it client side defect or server side defect?
How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Openfire generally pings the client on a regular interval to check if the client is alive. When the client fails to respond within the specified timeout, the server infers the client has disconnected.

The error you are getting is page not found error which basically means that either there is some problem with your listening port or network.

However since you are using loopback address, the network possibility is ruled out. Check your server port as I (even though the code is not given for reference) feel that your client may not have any problems. Just make sure the binding address is up and right.

Comment: If I change the server from Openfire to Erlang will solve that problem?

Comment: I would suggest you to try and change the ping interval settings in the Openfire admin console first, as I have worked with Openfire and it works fine.

Comment: I tried from default 360 seconds to 5 seconds, 10 seconds, 15 seconds but still getting an same error!

Comment: Are you publishing your presence on a regular interval? As incorrect stanzas also result in disconnection from the server. Check for the presence stanza builder parameters as I don't think its an Openfire issue.

Comment: Thanks to you, but there was another defect in setting of Openfire, anyhow solved this issue.

Comment: Could you describe the other OpenFire setting which you found solved the problem? Intermittent '404 - Invalid SID' errors seem to be fairly common with OpenFire + BOSH, it's been determined that OF's current BOSH implementation has some issues. Many revert to alternative BOSH connection managers such as Punjab to avoid the intermittent disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my code (I'm using my version of Candy Chat), and the problem was I wasn't calling the `BOSH _proto` version of `_doDisconnect` in time.

```
_doDisconnect: function ()
    {
        this.sid = null;
        this.rid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4294967295);
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem('strophe-bosh-session');
    },
```

You must make sure this is called before your code calls the Strophe `_changeConnectStatus` function for a disconnect. Or at least set the current connection `this.sid = null`.

In other words, you have to make sure Strophe nulls the current "sid" value so the next ping sends no "sid" or a new one (I think none, but might be a new one). If not, your client side next "send" ping has the old value in it even though the server now disconnecting. Then the server gives the not very informative 404 error, which is actually letting you know that that connection is no longer valid (which of course is what I wanted in the first place). Sort of a which came first, the chicken or the egg problem.

Hope that helps a little with one version of why that error comes up. The standard version of Candy Chat resets everything before every connection attempt, so it doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

update keepalive value at client side. default is 120 seconds.